# How to restart icewm from the command line?

Tags: icewm

I'm looking for a way to bind for example the Ctrl+Alt+Ins key combination to a command line that would restart icewm (just to make it read the configuration files again and be aware of the edits).

So what should go into that .icewm/keys file ?

`key "Alt+Ctrl+k" <tab> <...> ?`

Comment: just run `icewm --restart`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want IceWM to re-read its configuration, send it a `SIGHUP` signal:

```
killall -SIGHUP icewm
```

See the [Configuration](http://www.icewm.org/FAQ/IceWM-FAQ-4.html) chapter in the IceWM Manual.

Answer (score 6):

```
key "Alt+Ctrl+k" icewm --restart
```

according to [icewm](https://ice-wm.org/man/icewm) and [icewm-keys](https://ice-wm.org/man/icewm-keys) manpages for 1.4.2.

Comment: @JeffSchaller it looks like the OP already knows how to bind the key but needs the command. See the last sentence in the question: "*So what should go into that .icewm/keys file ?*"

Answer (score 2):

I've been using

```
icewm --replace
```

Less chance of making some dumb mistake while using 'kill'.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/159540/11878  Though it's on the Ubuntu SE site, there's nothing distro-specific about the answer.

Comment: Depends on your goal. If you want you current session vanished and all open windows closed without warning, this may be what you are looking for. (Using IceWM 1.3.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).)